# posts within a certain post tag_ID

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to be able to use the has_term function to not only find the category but also use a conditional statement to do something if a post is matches the has_term. this doesn't work. eg:

```
if (has_term('28', 'product_cat')){
    //do something
}
```

this only does something when viewing tag_ID 28 but not posts within tag_ID 28.

Comment: Where did you put that code ?

Comment: within single.php and sidebar.php. i'm using it for jigoshop that uses product_cat as a custom post category

Answer (score 0):

The function has_term usage is:

```
<?php has_term( $term, $taxonomy, $post ) ?>
```

[Check this codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) for more details. I think you need to specify the post id also in that function. The default will check the current post only.

Comment: i want all post ID's within term 28 though